# How to check if angular already has a module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am checking if angular already knows my module like this right now:

```
try {
  angular.module('myModule');
}
catch (err) {
  angular.module('myModule', []);
}
```

Is there a better way? angular seems to miss a "hasModule()" method..

Answer (score 0):

I would write a method to check that.

```
function isModuleAvailable(name) {
  try {
    return angular.module(name).name === name;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Usage: `isModuleAvailable('App')` returns `true` or `false`